# System requirements

Tags: eevee-render-engine, system

I have a laptop with 4GB RAM (hp i3) Intel graphic card of 2gb. I have downloaded blender 2.82. Is it ok to use that in my laptop? I am going to use only Eevee engine. Will using blender cause a damage for my laptop?

Comment: Hi, welcome! You could try to use a recent blender version on your laptop, you cannot do any harm, but it ould also not work, if your pc is not recent or powerful enough. Anyway you can always download older blender versions (try 2.7x) and be able to do quite a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll be totally fine, if you're going to use Eevee only, then there's really nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any software could damage a PC / LAPTOP, if the hardware is ok (if a FAN is broken, any software could damage you computer).

You can use cycle or Eevee without any problem.

The only problem you could face is that performances are slow (slow rendering time for example, but you can use a cloud render platform if you don't want to stress you computer).

Comment: could you please tell me about cloud rendering and hoe to do that?

Comment: check google --> https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+cloud+rendering&cad=h
You upload your .blend file and request for a render. Based on the duration of the render, some credits will be deducted from your account. Usually it's quite cheap.